# Postgres Denormalized CSV Generation

Tags: postgresql, csv, export-to-csv

I have a postgres database with the data structure that is set up as follows.

I have an evaluation table and a prescription table. An evaluation can have many prescriptions associated with it. A Prescription can only have one evaluation associated with it.

The problem I'm having is that I want to be able to export a CSV of this data. Expect, I want the format to be all on one line in the CSV. If an evaluation has 1 prescription, there should be a column in the csv for prescription_name_1, etc. If the evaluation has 5 prescriptions, I want it to expand to prescription_name_1, prescription_name_2, prescription_name_3, prescription_name_4, prescription_name_5. Effectively denormalizing this data.

Not sure if this is possible with the database or if I'm going to have to stick to the application layer for this type of logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query, that get denormalized data:

```
SELECT evaluation.name || '_' || CASE WHEN prescription.counts IS NULL
  THEN 0
                           ELSE prescription.counts END
  AS denormalized_name
FROM evaluations evaluation LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                                  SELECT
                                    count(id) counts,
                                    evaluation_id
                                  FROM prescription
                                  GROUP BY evaluation_id
                                ) prescription
    ON evaluation.id = prescription.evaluation_id
```

Then, you can copy it to csv via:

```
Copy (%query%) To '/var/test.csv' With CSV;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but something like this might work.  Assuming your prescription -> evaluation relationships are in an object named `prescription`:

```
create table prescription (
  prescription_name text,
  evaluation_name text
);
```

Then you could use an array, cast it to text and then strip out the visual elements that render the array -- the opening and closing curly braces:

```
with array_query as (
  select
    p1.evaluation_name, array (
      select p2.prescription_name
      from prescription p2
      where p1.evaluation_name = p2.evaluation_name
    )::text as prescriptions
  from
    prescription p1
  group by
    p1.evaluation_name
)
select
  evaluation_name || ',' ||
  replace (replace (prescriptions, '{', ''), '}', '')
from array_query
```

Input:

```
insert into prescription values ('Prescription 1', 'Eval 1');
insert into prescription values ('Prescription 2', 'Eval 1');
insert into prescription values ('Prescription 3', 'Eval 1');
insert into prescription values ('Prescription 4', 'Eval 2');
insert into prescription values ('Prescription 5', 'Eval 2');
insert into prescription values ('Prescription 6', 'Eval 2');
insert into prescription values ('Prescription 7', 'Eval 2');
```

Output:

```
Eval 2,"Prescription 4","Prescription 5","Prescription 6","Prescription 7"
Eval 1,"Prescription 1","Prescription 2","Prescription 3"
```